# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'kernel_size' error occured in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

```
#vgg16
class  VGGBase(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VGGBase,self).__init__()
        self.conv1_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3,64, kernel_size=3,padding=1,strides=1),
        self.conv1_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,64, kernel_size=3, padding=1,strides=1),
        self.pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),

        self.conv2_1  =  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,128, kernel_size=3, padding=1,strides= 1),
        self.conv2_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,128, kernel_size=3,padding=1,strides= 1),
        self.pool2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
 def call(self,x):
        x = relu(self.conv1_1(x))
        x = relu(self.conv1_2(x))
        x = relu(self.pool1(x))

        x = relu(self.conv2_1(x))
        x = relu(self.conv2_2(x))
        x = relu(self.pool2(x))
```

This is tensrflow 2.0 and got the error of got 
multiple values for argument 'kernel_size"

> File "/home/jake/Gits/ssd_tensorflow/model.py", line 10, in **init**
>       self.conv1_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3,64, kernel_size=3,padding=1,strides=1,input_shape=input_shape), TypeError:
>   **init**() got multiple values for argument 'kernel_size'

Comment: Did you get a traceback that shows the failing line?

Comment: tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3,64, kernel_size=3,padding=1,strides=1,input_shape=input_shape),

Comment: What is the purpose of `,` there at the end?

Comment: @JintoLonappan - I'm not sure what the purpose is, but the result is that `self.conv2_1` is a single item tuple.

Answer (score 1):

The call signature for `Conv2D` is long, but starts with `Conv2d(filter, kernel_size, ...)`. You called it with two positional arguments filling in `filter` and `kernel_size` and then tried to set `kernel_size=3`. Since `kernel_size` was already filled with a positional argument, you got the error.

Kernel size should be a two element tuple. You may have meant

```
self.conv1_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1, strides=1),
```

As an aside, `self.conv1_1` will be a 1 element tuple, which may be what you want. Otherwise, remove that ending comma.